# Heroku Rails 4 Puma app spawning extra instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, newrelic, puma

I'm running a basic Rails 4 (ruby 2.1.4) app on Heroku with a Puma config as follows:

```
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 1)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 6), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 6)
```

I currently do not have any ENV vars set so I should be defaulting to 1 worker.

The problem is, that while investigating a potential memory leak, it appears that 2 'instances' of my web.1 dyno are running, at least according to NewRelic.

I have heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics enabled and it shows my memory footprint at ~400MB.  On NewRelic it shows my footprint at ~200MB AVG across 2 'instances'.

`heroku:ps` shows:

```
=== web (1X): `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
web.1: up 2014/10/30 13:49:29 (~ 4h ago)
```

So why would NewRelic think I have 2 instances running?  If I do a heroku:restart NewRelic will see only 1 instance for awhile and then bump up to 2.   Is this something Heroku is doing but not reporting to me, or is it a Puma thing even though workers should be set to 1.

Comment: I'm having almost the exact same problem (I have 2 Heroku dynos, 1 Puma worker, showing 4 instances). Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 2):

See the Feb 17, 2015 release of [New Relic 3.10.0.279](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/ruby-release-notes/ruby-agent-3100279) which addresses this specific issue when tracking Puma instances. I'm guessing since your app is running on Heroku, you have `preload_app!` set in your Puma config so this should apply.

From the release notes:

> Metrics no longer reported from Puma master processes.
>   When using Puma's cluster mode with the preload_app! configuration directive, the agent will no longer start its reporting thread in the Puma master process. This should result in more accurate instance counts, and more accurate stats on the Ruby VMs page (since the master process will be excluded).

I'm testing the updated on a project with a simular issue and it seems to be reporting more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

It's because Puma has always 1 master process from which all the workers are spawned.

So, the instance count will come from the following:

`1 (master process) + <N_WORKER>`